# unable to read serialized data as message body in msmq c# 3.0

Tags: c#-3.0

This is my method to send message to a private Q

```
using (MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue(MessageQueueName))
        {
            using (System.Messaging.Message newMessage = new System.Messaging.Message(MessageBody,
                new System.Messaging.ActiveXMessageFormatter()))
            {
                newMessage.Label = MessageLabel;
                newMessage.Priority = Priority;
                msgQ.Send(newMessage);
            }

        }
```

I have an order object which i serialize and send as message body. The serialized object is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<OrderInfo>
    <OrderID>11111</OrderID>
    <OrderDetails>
        <LineItem>
            <ProductDetails>
                <Name>qwqwqw</Name>
                <Manufacturer>asasas</Manufacturer>
                <UPC>12222222222</UPC>
                <sku>2132</sku>
                <Price>12.21</Price>
            </ProductDetails>
            <Quantity>1</Quantity>
        </LineItem>
    </OrderDetails>
</OrderInfo>
```

This is my method to receive that message in a windows service

```
 void queue_ReceiveCompleted(object sender, ReceiveCompletedEventArgs asyncResult)
{
    // Connect to the queue.
    MessageQueue mq = (MessageQueue)sender;

    // End the asynchronous Receive operation.
    Message m = mq.EndReceive(asyncResult.AsyncResult);

    m.Formatter = new System.Messaging.ActiveXMessageFormatter()

    //Get Filedata from body
    OrdrInfo qMessage = (OrdrInfo)XMLUtil.Deserialize(m.Body.ToString(), typeof(OrdrInfo));

}
```

when I try to look at m.Body in quickwatch this is what it states

m.Body.Message = Cannot find a formatter capable of reading this message.

m.Body.StackTrace =    at System.Messaging.Message.get_Body()

Answer (score 3):

Hopefully you're not still stuck on this, but as it came up top of my search when running into the same problem.

As no one had answered it, here is one answer that I've just found else where (thanks [TechRepublic](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6170794.html)).  This code assume that "MyType" is a typically basic message that can be read by XML Serialisation - this means it is marked as serializable and all data to be sent/reconstructed is in public get/set properties.

Code is:

```
MessageQueue msgQ = new MessageQueue(@".\private$\CreateNewEntity");

msgQ.Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new []{typeof(MyType)});            
var msg = msgQ.Receive();

msgQ.Close();
return msg.Body as MyType;
```